# How to re-define the argument type of an event with a sub-type of the original type and refer to the original event

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

Essentially I have an interface IACollection that defines an event taking in an argument IAItem, and then another interface IBCollection that inherits from IACollection that re-defines this event to take in IBItem which inherits from IAItem.

My trouble is that when I try to create a class that implements the interface IBCollection, I can't seem to implement both events in a way that there is really only one actual event -- which there is because an event that takes in an IAItem should be able to take in an IBItem just fine since it is an IAItem.

Below are my two attempts at a solution, but both fail for different reasons. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

```
using System;

public interface IAItem { }

public interface IBItem : IAItem { }

public interface IACollection
{
    event Action<IAItem> ItemAdded;
}

public interface IBCollection : IACollection
{
    new event Action<IBItem> ItemAdded;
}

public class Collection1 : IBCollection
{
    public event Action<IBItem> ItemAdded;

    // Won't work because the -= won't remove the same
    // lambda expression that was added before.
    event Action<IAItem> IACollection.ItemAdded
    {
        add { ItemAdded += (arg) => value(arg); }
        remove { ItemAdded -= (arg) => value(arg); }    // Won't remove
    }
}

public class Collection2 : IBCollection
{
    // Won't work in practice because Action<IB> cannot be
    // converted to Action<IA>, even though it should
    // theoretically work since IB can be converted to IA.
    public event Action<IBItem> ItemAdded
    {
        add { itemAdded += value; }     // Compile Error
        remove { itemAdded -= value; }      // Compile Error
    }

    event Action<IAItem> IACollection.ItemAdded
    {
        add { itemAdded += value; }
        remove { itemAdded -= value; }
    }

    private event Action<IAItem> itemAdded;
}
```